# NIntegrate with big error estimates

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate a 4-dimensional integral using standard wolfram mathematica methods, but I can't get rid of a big calculation error.
My integral

```
   NIntegrate[-((
  Gamma[3/5 - I t] Gamma[1/15 + I x] Gamma[28/15 - I x - I y] Gamma[
    1/15 + I y] Gamma[
    3/10 - I z] Gamma[-(2/5) + I t + I z])/((-(1/10) + I t + 
     1/2 (-(1/15) - I x)) (3/5 + I t + 1/2 (-(44/15) + I y) + I z) (7/
     10 + 1/2 (-(28/15) + I x + I y) + I z) Gamma[-(1/10) + 
     I t] Gamma[9/10 - I t - I z] Gamma[1/5 + I z])), {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 25000}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 40, MinRecursion -> 5]
```

[image: error estimates]
In spherical system

```
NIntegrate[-r^3 Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 
   2]]^2 ((Gamma[2/3 - I r Cos[Subscript[t, 2]]] Gamma[
       1/6 - I r Cos[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]]] Gamma[-(1/
         3) + I r Cos[Subscript[t, 2]] + 
        I r Cos[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]]] Gamma[
       1/7 + I r Cos[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 
          2]]] Gamma[
       12/7 - I r Cos[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]] - 
        I r Sin[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]]] Gamma[
       1/7 + I r Sin[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 
          2]]])/(Gamma[-(1/6) + I r Cos[Subscript[t, 2]]] Gamma[
       5/6 - I r Cos[Subscript[t, 2]] - 
        I r Cos[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]]] Gamma[
       1/3 + I r Cos[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]]] (-(1/6) + 
        I r Cos[Subscript[t, 2]] + 
        1/2 (-(1/7) - 
           I r Cos[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]])) (2/
        3 + I r Cos[Subscript[t, 2]] + 
        I r Cos[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]] + 
        1/2 (-(20/7) + 
           I r Sin[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]])) (5/
        6 + I r Cos[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]] + 
        1/2 (-(12/7) + 
           I r Cos[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 2]] + 
           I r Sin[p] Sin[Subscript[t, 1]] Sin[Subscript[t, 
             2]])))), {r, 0, Infinity}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {Subscript[t, 
  1], 0, Pi}, {Subscript[t, 2], 0, Pi}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 20000}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 40, MinRecursion -> 5]
```

[image: error estimates]

How can you reduce the error by Wolfram Mathematica methods?

**Edit:** Initial analytical expression is
[image: initial expression]
after which I shift the integration contour

```
    {Subscript[s, 2] -> I x + 1/15, Subscript[s, 3] -> I y + 1/15, 
 Subscript[v, 1] -> I z + 1/2 + 1/5, Subscript[v, 2] -> I t - 1/10}
```

i get the first integral

The original integral by naive power counting must converge

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142266/discussion-on-question-by-heliodor-nintegrate-with-big-error-estimates).